# Flutter Hours Based Calendar / Hours Selecting with Swipe-down

Tags: android, flutter, dart, calendar

In the desktop version, such as Google Calendar, clocks can be selected using the scroll (scroll-down). I want to be able to do the same with Flutter. So far I have not been able to find an example. I've tried many times, but it didn't work out the way I wanted. Is there a library where I can do this?

I want to do that with Flutter

[image: Hours based calendar timeline]

Google Calendar Web;

[image]